# apacahe shiro ,after 1 successful basic authentication it returns true for all wrong credentials

Tags: basic-authentication, shiro

I'm using Apache Shiro for my Rest service project  and I have troubles getting it to work as intended.

For rest service,I use basic authentication and as first,when I send wrong username,It returns 401 as expected.

Then I send correct user name and password,It returns 200 as expected.
As 3th step,When I send again wrong username,It returns 200,should return 401.

I think after first successful login,It doesnt need any authentication process again.How can I force it to authenticate for every request?
I couldnt find any reason or any parameter I should add in my shiro.ini.

This is my shiro.ini:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing may be the result of your client. Before a client will send credentials to a server *typically* has to ask for them (responding with a 401), the client will the add the auth header.  A client can work around this using "preemptive" auth, which will send the `Authorization` header on the initial request.

Your server is likely also configured to use cookies, which the server will process first and then return a 200 (and the client would never send the new credentials).

If this is just a REST server/client setup, you could disable session creation, using the `noSessionCreation` filter.

https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#default_filters

If you are still stuck take a look at your HTTP logs and watch for the headers (specifically `Authorization` and an `Cookie` headers).

Comment: I was testing via postman, I saw postman sends the JSESSIONID to myserver. Once I send with correct user name and password,cuz of JSESSİON ID then all requests is accepted.I disabled to send JSESSION ID and now it works.Thanks for your kind help